# How can I do an `if` check if the typed word is equal to some word in a string list in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, c-strings, string-comparison

How can I do an `if` check if the typed word is equal to some word in a string list in C?
Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

char input[20];
char* strings[] = {"apple","banana"};

printf("try to hit one of my favorite fruits:\n");
scanf("%s", input);

if(input == strings[]){
     printf("you got it right %s is one of my favorite fruits!", input);
}else{
    printf("you missed");
     }
}
```

Comment: C strings are arrays. You can't use ==. Use strcmp or strncmp.

Comment: At least use `scanf("%19s", input);` or some safer input means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h> //you need string.h to use strcmp()

int main(){

char input[20];
char* strings[] = {"apple","banana"};

printf("try to hit one of my favorite fruits:\n");
scanf("%s", input);
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){ //2 is the length of the array
if(strcmp(input,strings[i])==0){ //strcmp() compares two strings
     printf("you got it right %s is one of my favorite fruits!", input);
     return 0;
}
}
printf("you missed");
}
```

Comment: Strongly suggest using `sizeof(strings) / sizeof(*strings)` for the array length not literal `2`.

Answer (score -1):

To compare strings in C, you must use the [`strcmp()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) function:

```
bool hit = false;
for (size_t i = 0; !hit && i < sizeof strings / sizeof *strings; ++i)
{
  hit = strcmp(input, strings[i] == 0);
}

if (hit)
{
  printf("You hit one of my favorites!\n");
}
else
{
  printf("You missed, too bad.\n");
}
```

Note that the loop ends as soon as a hit is found, then after the loop the `hit` variable is checked to determine the proper message to print.

You should also check that `scanf()` didn't fail, it has a return value for this reason.

Answer (score -1):

The condition in the if statement

```
f(input == strings[]){
```

is syntactically incorrect at least because there is missed an index in the subscript operator `strings[]`.

But if you will write the condition syntactically correctly as for example

```
f(input == strings[0]){
```

it will not make a sense because there are compared two pointers instead of comparing strings.

To compare two strings you should use the standard C string function `strcmp`.

You could write a separate function that checks whether a string is present in an array of pointers to strings.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int is_present( const char * s1[], size_t n, const char *s2 )
{
    size_t i = 0;
    
    while ( i < n && strcmp( s1[i], s2 ) != 0 ) ++i;
    
    return i != n;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char input[20];
    const char * strings[] = { "apple", "banana" };
    const size_t N = sizeof( strings ) / sizeof( *strings );

    printf( "try to hit one of my favorite fruits:\n" );
    scanf( "%s", input );

    if( is_present( strings, N, input ) ){
        printf("you got it right %s is one of my favorite fruits!", input);
    }else{
        printf("you missed");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
try to hit one of my favorite fruits:
apple
you got it right apple is one of my favorite fruits!
```